# WSO2 Data Analytics Server - Function Logstash

Tags: logstash, wso2-das

Thanks for the opportunity.

I´m to configure DAS(WSO2 Data Analytics Server) in my environment but I need that appear and capture logs with the logstash.

In the DAS exist this caracteristic?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking at is to publish DAS logs to Logstash. Please check this [article](https://medium.com/@chamilad/monitoring-wso2-logs-with-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-or-grafana-1f880f6ed056) which explains steps to setup with WSO2 ESB. You can follow the same for DAS.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. At true I would like of to capture events in log(wso2 api management, esb etc) through DAS. Is possible? Or I will have to install logstash to make this function? I am not achieve to make this with DAS.